Finding the amount of update and delete operations in a Big query table
We have lots of BQ tables in our organization and we want to understand which ones have update or delete operations, and what amount.
Metrics in BQ don't expose this. I'm having to join snapshots to see if this is the case. Very ineffective.
What are possibilities to see this?

In BigQuery you can query the audit log and filter for update and delete statement to get the operations performed on each table. BigQuery logs all data access activity including update and delete to Cloud Audit logs.
